# Stuck on Target Disk Mode due to Firmware Password

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, password, firmware, target-disk-mode

The MacBook Pro 2014 (macOS High Sierra, A1502) I’m using has a firmware password set. I tried to boot into target disk mode and it asks for this password even after turning it off/on. I tried many key combinations, SMC reset, <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, etc, none of which worked.

I just want to boot from the main drive again so it works as usual. Is there anything I can do apart from waiting until Monday to resolve it at my school? I need this thing for the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need your firmware password to boot into anything other than macOS (which is why it's called a *firmware* password). If you can't remember your firmware password your only real option is to take your computer to the Apple Store. I believe I read online somewhere they'll have a special key or something like that so you can go in and reset your firmware password or remove it, then you'll be able to boot into target disk mode.

Comment: Also, an Apple Store (or authorized service provider) should require you to provide proof of ownership before they'll reset the firmware password. The firmware password is a security feature, and it's designed to be hard to bypass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentioned, I want to boot macOS but I can't find a way to reset the boot order without the firmware password. I don't own this computer nor set the password.